# Using postgres thru ODBC in python 2.7

Tags: python, postgresql, odbc, pypyodbc, postgresapp

- I have installed  Postgres.app and started it.
- I have pip installed pypyodbc
- I have copied the hello world lines from the Pypyodbc docs, and received the
  error below.  any ideas what the issue might be?

Here is my code

```
  from __future__ import print_function
  import pypyodbc
  import datetime
  conn = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={psqlOBDC};SERVER=localhost")
```

And I receive this error:

```
File "/ob/pkg/python/dan27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 975, in ctrl_err
  err_list.append((from_buffer_u(state), from_buffer_u(Message), NativeError.value))
File "/ob/pkg/python/dan27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 482, in UCS_dec
  uchar = buffer.raw[i:i + ucs_length].decode(odbc_decoding)
File "/ob/pkg/python/dan27/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_32.py", line 11, in decode
  return codecs.utf_32_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf32' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1:   truncated data
```

what am I doing wrong?

Do I need to somehow initialize the DB / tables first?  it is a weird error if that is the issue.

Comment: Does Postgres.app actually include an ODBC driver? A quick look at its [home page](http://postgresapp.com/) seems to suggest that it doesn't.

Comment: Gord, there is no problem. On my Fedora I used `yum install postgresql-odbc` and it installs unixodbc and other required packages. For Windows there is separate installer. I use their ODBC driver and I think it is one of the best ODBC drivers I know (I had some problems with Oracle and Informix drivers while PostgreSQL just works).

Comment: I think ODBC driver is installed correctly but there is problem with ConnectString.

Comment: @MichałNiklas Your tests may not accurately reflect the environment that the asker is working in. From what I gather, Postgres.app is a stand-alone Mac application that provides a PostgreSQL server without having to actually install PostgreSQL. Tests under Linux (or Windows) with a complete PostgreSQL install (and an explicitly installed ODBC driver for PostgreSQL) could conceivably behave quite differently.

Comment: @MichałNiklas indeed you are right.  I used the standalone installer from Postgres itself.  then I pip installed postgresql-odbc.  This should work, but I can see the non-odbc Postgres drivers is where most of the community spends its efforts, so I have given up on the odbc path.  (still if someone actually solves the problem in the OSX context, I will select that answer for the larger communities knowledge.)  thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code on my Fedora machine and it started when I changed connect string to something like:

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect("Driver={PostgreSQL};Server=IP address;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;")
```

You can find more connect strings for PostgreSQL and ODBC at: https://connectionstrings.com/postgresql-odbc-driver-psqlodbc/

Comment: Hi, how can i find the postgresql driver for macos